# Need javascript sorter (pref. jquery) that doesn't clone elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter

So far I've tried [Tiny Table Sorter](http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter/), [Tables on Cows](http://github.com/mixonic/tables_on_cows/tree/master), [Sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/), and [Yoast's Sortable-table plugin](http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/). I have the last one currently installed on a [test page here](http://beerlyrics.com/jimmy-jones/). I finally don't get a conflict w/ the qtip script I'm running on the same page.  I understand that the conflicts arrive from a sorter that uses cloned elements. Unfortunately, the actual sorting function is buggy in this last one. Given my technical limitations, it is easier for me to look elsewhere for a sorter than try to learn/figure out why this one doesn't work.

Comment: `Sorttable` that you linked to does not clone elements nor create new elements. It sorts the rows in place. Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: I run into two problems with these javascript sorters. One is that they sometimes clone elements which renders the other important script I'm using useless.  If they don't clone, then they sort improperly. Click on the year 2010 in the test page I have linked to above and you will see what I mean. I now have the script that Breadtruck suggested installed.

Comment: @adam-So what did you end up finding out?

Comment: Thanks for checking back.  I'm at a holding pattern with this unfortunately. I found that the Tablesorter you recommended below worked out well w/ custom regex. But I later found an updated script that would let me filter and paginate which was ideal. And now there are errors when paginating and it once again breaks Qtip. If I get the pagination to work (which may be simple just by looking at the Error Console), I will also try cluetips like you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this jquery plugin http://tablesorter.com/ with the cluetips plugin without any problems. If you decide to punt and try something different!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I installed it and am having a similar problem I have had w/ other scripts. Try clicking the year 2010 in the test page I linked to above. The text data should all flow up to the top when sorting descending.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your source, your numbers have a space around them probably for spacing and the text A2, FA does not, I think this could be why your not getting the consistent sorting that you desire. Try removing all spacing and adding some padding using css.

Even then you still might have problems with sorting because I think the sorter will treat those numbers like text, and therefore certain numbers will come before other numbers because it is evaluating the value like text instead of number. I went to your example and on the 3rd click of the column header I got what I am talking about.

I am not sure you will be able to get around this. Do a test by just removing anything from that column but numbers and see if it will sort correctly!